# HTTPS Communication between two microservices

Tags: spring, https, microservices

My situation is this:

I have 3 microservices(Spring Boot applications). I want to achieve https communication between `service A` and `service B` but not able to do `HTTPS` communication between `service A`  and `service C`.

Also, `service A` is a server which is secured with `SSL` and `service B` and `service C` are ***clients***.

I have tried to create `server.jks` where I have server certificate and imported certificate from `agent.jks`.

`agent.jks`on the other hand has his certificate and imported certificate from `server.jks`. So `keystore` and `truststore` are ready (at least I think so).

`Service A` has `server.jks` in `/resources` folder and `Service B` has `agent.jks` in `/resources` folder.

Common Name: `localhost` for both. `Service C` has **nothing** in `/resources` folder.
I have added certificate from `server` to `cacerts`.

`SSL` configuration for `Service A` looks like:

```
server:
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-alias: localhost
    key-store-type: jks
    key-store: classpath:server.jks
    key-store-password: password
    key-password: password
    trust-store: classpath:server.jks
    trust-store-password: password
```

Now, I want to call endpoint `service A` from `service B`(via `RestTemplate`) and receive some feedback(`String`) and when I do the same from `service C` I want to have `error`, `exception` or whatever.

Comment: Hey @Ashley, Welcome to SO ! Are you able to make call `service A` from `service B` and get the `response` ? And when `service C` calls `service A` you want to have error? Like `service A` should respond back with error? Right?

Comment: Yes I can do service A service B communication and thats ok, but I can do now service C and service A communication and I don't want that.

Comment: @AshleyTroyer, Can you help us provide the exception details so we can quickly analyze it and help you?

Comment: Exception does not pop up, that is the problem. Why I am able to establish communication between C and A and B and A? I only want B and A communication, therefore I put certificate B into A keystore.